# Exact string match for query purposes

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to query a certain string/word and query a bunch of results pertaining to it but having an issue with the SQL statement.
For example: when I try and search for property_code "TA001" with the current code, it will query back TA001, CTA001, JTA001, etc.  I only want the exact submitted result.

I have tried replacing the LIKE function with an = and also removing the wildcard %'s but wouldn't return any results.  any help would be appreciated. here is the code:

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
$search_output = "";
if(isset($_POST['searchquery']) && $_POST['searchquery'] != ""){
$searchquery = preg_replace('#[^a-z 0-9]-#i', '', trim(strtoupper($_POST['searchquery'])));
if($_POST['filter1'] == "properties"){
    $sqlCommand = "(SELECT id, property_code, street, street2, city, state, zip FROM properties WHERE property_code LIKE '% $searchquery %')";
} else if($_POST['filter1'] == "vendor"){
    $sqlCommand = "SELECT id, vendor_name FROM vendor WHERE vendor_name LIKE '%$searchquery%'";
} 
    include_once("database.php");
    $query = mysql_query($sqlCommand) or die(mysql_error());
$count = mysql_num_rows($query);
if($count > 1){
    $search_output .= "<hr />$count results for <strong>$searchquery</strong><hr />$sqlCommand<hr />";
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
        $id = $row["id"];
        $property_code = $row["property_code"];
        $street = $row["street"];
        $street2 = $row["street2"];
        $city = $row["city"];
        $state = $row["state"];
        $zip = $row["zip"];
        $search_output .= "Item ID: $id: - $property_code, $street, $street2, $city, $state $zip<br />";
            } // close while
} else {
    $search_output = "<hr />0 results for <strong>$searchquery</strong><hr />$sqlCommand";
}
}
?>
```

Comment: if you want exact, why are you using LIKE and wild card %

Comment: You're right it should be:  WHERE property_code='$searchquery'..are you sure you have a row with that information? Also you need to make sure you're careful about XSS when echoing out your results.

Comment: Replacing the `LIKE` query with an `=` (etc.) is exactly what I would have suggested. You should look at the values in that column to see if there's whitespace or other unexpected characters that are causing the exact match to fail. Also, you should be using prepared statements (PDO) to prevent against SQL injection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line:

```
   $sqlCommand = "(SELECT id, property_code, street, street2, city, state, zip FROM properties WHERE property_code LIKE '% $searchquery %')";
```

You have got a space in LIKE condition between '% and $searchquery - that's problem one.

And If you want to search only records starting with $searchquery string maybe try it like this:

```
if($_POST['filter1'] == "properties"){
$sqlCommand = "SELECT id, property_code, street, street2, city, state, zip FROM properties WHERE property_code LIKE '{$searchquery}%'";
} else if($_POST['filter1'] == "vendor"){
    $sqlCommand = "SELECT id, vendor_name FROM vendor WHERE vendor_name LIKE '{$searchquery}%'";
}
```

And if you want exact match try this:

```
if($_POST['filter1'] == "properties"){
    $sqlCommand = "SELECT id, property_code, street, street2, city, state, zip FROM properties WHERE property_code = '{ $searchquery'";
} else if($_POST['filter1'] == "vendor"){
    $sqlCommand = "SELECT id, vendor_name FROM vendor WHERE vendor_name = '{$searchquery}'";
}
```

Comment: thanks guys. i'll look into all this tomm and see what i can find that works